# XenCenter cannot connect to my remote XenServer

Tags: citrix, xen, dyndns

I'm currently working on a virtu project for my IT school. I have this PC with XenServer only, used for the said project. I :

- Placed it at my home
- Connected it to my router
- Deactivated DHCP for its address
- Configurated the ports so I can access it from outside
- Registered a dynDNS domain
- Tested it : I can type the dynDNS address from outside and I see the XenServer page (Nothing but the links to XenCenter and "Citrix Systems, Inc. XenServer 6.2.0")

So I tried to register the XenServer in XenCenter and I get ERROR ! "Unable to connect to 'whatever.net'. The connection was refused. Check etc and try again."

Is there something I am missing? Btw sorry but English is not my native language.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `/etc/hosts.allow` file. It has to contain the next line:

`xapi: 1.2.3.4 your.ip.address. 192.168.10.`